# I have to call 3 patch restful endpoints, but if one fails, revert all the others. Is this possible?

Tags: java, spring, rest

So, i have a restfull api endpoint "A" that when called, need to get the body information and send a patch request to other 2 endpoints "B" and "C". The thing is, i have to assure that either both of them go through successfully or none goes.

Calling endpoins in the following order: B,then C.

If B patch is successfull > call C Patch.
If C patch fails, then "rollback" patch B.

Comment: Why don't you patch all values at once ? Like embedding them in the same request ?

Comment: It's 2 endpoints from different systems. I have to patch info in system B, and info in System C. They can't be inconsistent

Comment: It strictly depends on the logic that is performed within `B`. What happens there? Persisting into DB or some in-memory operations or both?

Comment: persistence into db